# My login procedure is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to access some page text that requires me to be logged in first.

The login page is = https://utdirect.utexas.edu/

and my attempt so far is like this,

```
Response res = Jsoup
        .connect("https://utdirect.utexas.edu/") // this is the login page
        .header("LOGON", "mySchoolID")
        .header("PASSWORDS", "mySchoolIDPassword")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();


    Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies(); // cookies to keep me logged in



    // This is the page that required me to be loged in first
    Document doc =   Jsoup.connect("https://utdirect.utexas.edu/apps/degree/audits/requests/history/") 
            .cookies(loginCookies).get();
        Elements e = doc.getAllElements();

        for(Element e1 : e){
            Log.i("e.text()" , e.text);
        }
```

The problem is that the one that was printed out is the login page NOT the page that i want.

Any idea what's the solution to this one?

Answer (score 2):

Read the login form before posting. You are missing few parameters. Check them for each loging.

---

```
    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://utdirect.utexas.edu/")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .timeout(12000)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

    Connection.Response loginFormFilled = Jsoup.connect("https://utdirect.utexas.edu/")
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .followRedirects(true)
                .referrer("https://utdirect.utexas.edu/")
                .data("CDT","20140103191944")
                .data("NEW_PASSWORD", "")
                .data("CONFIRM_NEW_PASSWORD", "")
                .data("LOGON", "user")
                .data("PASSWORDS", "pass")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

     Map<String, String> cookies = loginFormFilled.cookies();
```

Comment: and how exactly i keep the cookies for me to able to access https://utdirect.utexas.edu/apps/degree/audits/requests/history/ ? Thanks in advance!